# How to do Many to 2 constraint in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables that I need to create using SQL query, the first table is called Employees, the second table is called Departments.

How do I create a table to force the constraint "Many to 2" from Employees to Departments?

Comment: Please clarify what "many to 2" means - are you saying that an Employee can only be associated with exactly 2 Departments?

Answer (score 1):

Many-to-many, like one-to-many and many-to-one can be modeled in several ways - the *canonical* way to do it is via a mapping table:

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID | Other | Employee | Fields
```

**Department**

```
DepartmentID | Other | Department | Fields
```

**EmployeeDepartment**

```
EmployeeID | DepartmentID
```